# PhpStorm 2016.2 Command Line Tool fails to add artisan

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to add Laravel's artisan to my PhpStorm command line tool but I am getting the following error:

```
Problem
Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 3: Content is not allowed in prolog..
Command
{PATH}\artisan list --format=xml
Output                                              
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]  
An option with shortcut "q" already exists.
```

I'm assuming this is a fairly straightforward conflict of some sort but I can't seem to locate it. The only other command line tool I have set up is composer using the alias of c.

Comment: try remove project from phpstorm,and add again.Then run your command

Comment: I should have thought of that before posting a question. Thanks Imtiaz, that did it.